# Filter list based on elements string

Tags: python, list

I have a line of code which filters a list if it contains 'ab'

```
>>> l = ['a', 'ab', 'abc', 'bac']
>>> [x for x in l if 'ab' in x]
['ab', 'abc']
>>>
```

I now want to say do this if it contains ab or zz, but the below code isn't working

```
[x for x in l if '|'.join(['ab','zz']) in x]
```

Comment: `'|'.join(['ab', 'zz'])` is just the string `'ab|zz'` -- Python's `in` operator isn't going to interpret that as an `or`.  What you want is `[x for x in l if any(p in x for p in ['ab', 'zz'])]`

Comment: `[x for x in l if 'ab' in x or 'zz' in x]` ?

Answer (score 0):

You can try using a `or`:

```
[x for x in l if 'ab' in x or 'zz' in x]
```

---

```
>>> l = ['a', 'ab', 'abc', 'bac', 'zz', 'kkzz']
>>> [x for x in l if 'ab' in x or 'zz' in x]
>>> # ['ab', 'abc', 'zz', 'kkzz']
```